# HIPAA requirements for local server

Tags: mysql, hipaa, vlans

I am looking to create a ePHI database for a small physical therapy office and I would like some advice on some of the security that I will need to implement.

Most computers will most likely have no internet access, except for doing scheduled updates (checking Windows Updates, etc).

The data will be stored most likely in a MySQL database that is stored on a dedicated Ubuntu computer.  I am considering setting up a backup system of 2 external portable hard drives to do daily database backups and switched periodically (weekly/monthly/etc) with the hard drive that is stored in a safe deposit box.

There will probably be approximately 3 laptops purchased for doctors/nurses to use and most likely an android tablet for patients to fill out medical forms and sign forms.

At this time we are not planning to offer patients access to their medical records online.  All access to the database would be done on the LAN. I am thinking of setting up a VLAN.

I am considering creating ID badges for the staff that has an embedded NFC chip to be used for authorization to log into the database, etc.

I know I will need to encrypt the database and the external hard drives, but I have not decided which method would be the best.

One question I have been trying to decide on, is since all access is done on the LAN, would I need to use SSL connection?

I am also open for any advice/recommendations that you can offer me for this setup.

Comment: Make sure that the laptop drives are also fully encrypted - they are potentially the weakest link in what you have described so far. Will there by any VPN access? VLAN is used to segregate traffic, what sort of "unfriendly" traffic do you wish to separate?

Comment: Note that HIPAA doesn't prescribe any specific security measures regarding IT systems, rather it defines who may access medical data under what conditions and leaves implementation to the organization. Usually this means risk mitigation through standard security practices such as the ones you describe.

Comment: @user2813274: I might use VPN, I am not sure.  I was thinking of using the VLAN to limit the server and possibly the laptops from exposure to the internet except for when I do updates to the system.

Comment: @CampSoup1988 If you want to limit internet access to only for windows updates, wouldn't it make more sense to just use a whitelist on the firewall/router with [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb693717.aspx)?

Comment: @user2813274: I did not think of that.  I will look into your idea.  It probably would not only be for Windows Updates, but any other programs (Adobe Acrobat, Browser, etc) for both Windows and Ubuntu.  I would need to get a physical firewall and a switch if any of the computers will need unrestricted internet access (secretary, etc).  Correct?

Comment: For those computers with unrestricted internet access, those should be on a separate network, and that is where vlans could come into play, to make sure there is no cross-network traffic. Alternatively some companies choose to just have the wifi network as "open" and keep the wired network locked down - either could work. And while many companies do need a physical firewall, I would imagine a small office could probably get by with a router/firewall combo just fine.

Comment: @user2813274: The office is looking to use wifi so they could get laptops for the nurses/doctors to carry from room to another, and they are thinking of getting a tablet for new patients to be able to fill out all the paperwork.

Comment: I had been considering setting up SSL (most likely through OpenSSL) for the LAN communications between the computers and the server.  Would this be necessary if I set up MAC filtering to only allow approve devices from connecting to the network?

Comment: Yes, as MAC filtering is not secure at all - MAC addresses are easy to spoof, and easy to detect over wifi.